# How to get response from server?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I'm writing a class with requests to rest API (Yandex disk). I use volley, but I do have some problems with getting a response from it. You can check the rest API [here](https://tech.yandex.com/disk/rest/).

I use volley and I can get a response in the debugger, but not in my `Activity`.

Here is my `Requests` class

```
class Requests {
    private String response_of_server, token;
    private String url = "https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk";
    private Context context;

    Requests (String token, Context context) {
        this.token = token;
        this.context = context;
    }

    private void set_response_of_server(String response) {
        this.response_of_server = response;
    }

    String get_response() {
        return response_of_server;
    }

    void get_metadata_of_user() {

        try {
            /*Request*/

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.context);


            Response.ErrorListener error_listener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            };
            Response.Listener<String> response_listener = new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    set_response_of_server(response);
                }
            };

            StringRequest getRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url+"?fields=user", response_listener, error_listener) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("Host", "cloud-api.yandex.net");
                    params.put("Authorization", token);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            queue.add(getRequest);
            /*Request end*/

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the `MainActivity` where I want my response.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String ID_OF_APP = "Your token of app";
    private final String URL_FOR_CODE_QUERY = "https://oauth.yandex.com/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=" + ID_OF_APP;
    private String SAVED_TOKEN = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn_get_code = findViewById(R.id.btn_get_code); // send to get code page (yandex)
        btn_get_code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(URL_FOR_CODE_QUERY));
                    startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        Button btn_sign_in = findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
        btn_sign_in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText code_field = findViewById(R.id.code_field);
                String token = code_field.getText().toString();
                save_token(token);
                try {
                    if(check_token()) {
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are successfully signed in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // TODO change activity
                    }
                    else {}
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong. Please, check your connection and try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void save_token(String token) {
        SharedPreferences sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putString(SAVED_TOKEN, token);
        ed.apply();
    }

    private String load_token() {
        SharedPreferences sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sPref.getString(SAVED_TOKEN, "");
    }

    private boolean check_token() throws InterruptedException {
        String token = load_token();
        String result;
        Requests request = new Requests(token, this);
        request.get_metadata_of_user();
        result = request.get_response();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return !(result.equals("-1"));
    }
}
```

`check_token()` function at the moment should just make a toast with a response of the server. However, I cannot get the `Toast` or any response coming back from the server.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if that works. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a `Requests` class which has the function to call the server API which is `Asynchronous`. Hence, you will not get the `result` immediately after calling the `request.get_metadata_of_user();` in your `check_token()` function.

Hence I would like to suggest you modify your `Request` class like the following.

```
public class Requests {
    private String response_of_server, token;
    private String url = "https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk";
    private Context context;
    private HttpListener listener; // Add a listener to get the callback functionality

    Requests (String token, Context context, HttpListener listener) {
        this.token = token;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener; // initialize the listener here
    }

    private void set_response_of_server(String response) {
        this.response_of_server = response;
        listener.onResponseReceived(response); // Send the response back to the calling class
    }

    String get_response() {
        return response_of_server;
    }

    void get_metadata_of_user() {

        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.context);
            Response.ErrorListener error_listener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            };

            Response.Listener<String> response_listener = new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    set_response_of_server(response);
                }
            };

            StringRequest getRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url+"?fields=user", response_listener, error_listener) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("Host", "cloud-api.yandex.net");
                    params.put("Authorization", token);
                    return params;
                }
            };

            queue.add(getRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `HttpListener` class might look like the following. Create `HttpListener.java` and add the following code to create this as an interface.

```
public interface HttpListener {
    public void onResponseReceived();
}
```

Hence you need to implement this `interface` in your `MainActivity` like the following.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HttpListener {

    private final String ID_OF_APP = "Your token of app";

    // I fixed this part too. Please change if that is not useful
    private final String URL_FOR_CODE_QUERY = "https://oauth.yandex.com/authorize?response_type=" + SAVED_TOKEN + "&client_id=" + ID_OF_APP;
    private String SAVED_TOKEN = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // ... I omitted some code

        Button btn_sign_in = findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
        btn_sign_in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText code_field = findViewById(R.id.code_field);
                String token = code_field.getText().toString();
                save_token(token);

                try {
                    // if(check_token()) {
                        // The check_token function call is Async. This will not return immediately. Hence you might consider removing this if part. Simply just call the function and listen to the callback function when the response is received
                    // }

                    check_token(); // Simply call the function here
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void save_token(String token) {
        SharedPreferences sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putString(SAVED_TOKEN, token);
        ed.apply();
    }

    private String load_token() {
        SharedPreferences sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sPref.getString(SAVED_TOKEN, "");
    }

    // I changed the return type as this is not returning anything.
    private void check_token() throws InterruptedException {
        String token = load_token();
        String result;
        Requests request = new Requests(token, this);
        request.get_metadata_of_user();

        // You will not get the response immediately here. So omit these codes.
        // result = request.get_response();
        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // return !(result.equals("-1"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(String response) {
        // Here is your response. Now you can use your response
        // and can perform the next action here. 
    }
}
```

Please note that, the code is not tested. Please modify as per your requirement. I hope that helps you to understand the problem.

Comment: My editor doesn't see as a module as HttpListener. Where can I install it?

Comment: Just create a Java class like `HttpListener.java` and put the code there. This is just a simple java file that you need to create - like you have created your activity class.